# Onclick doen't work in the fragments of viewpager2

Tags: onclicklistener, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I have a viewpager2 with a tablayout with two tabs. In the fragment of each tab a have a button, but the onclick listener never is called when I click on it. I don't know where is the problem...

Fragment where I instance the viewpager2:

```kotlin
        ...
    @BindView(R.id.tab_viewpager2_bookings)
    lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout
    
    @BindView(R.id.viewpager2_booking)
    lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager2    
    
    ...
    
    val tabs = arrayOf(getString(R.string.bookings_on_going), getString(R.string.bookings_upcoming))
        tabLayout.tabGravity = TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL
        val adapter: FragmentStateAdapter = BookingsPagerAdapter(requireActivity(), tabs, ticketsOnGoing, ticketUpcoming, _user!!, bearerToken)
        viewPager.adapter = adapter
    
        if (ticketsOnGoing.isEmpty() && ticketUpcoming.isNotEmpty()) {
            viewPager.currentItem = 1
        }
        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = tabs[position]
        }.attach()
```

The XML with the viewpager2:

```xml
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
    
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_viewpager2_bookings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tabs_indicator_boardingpass"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/tabs_indicator_boardingpass"></com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
    
    
        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewpager2_booking"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/tab_viewpager2_bookings" />
             ...
```

The adapter:

```kotlin
        class BookingsPagerAdapter(fa: FragmentActivity, private val tabs:Array<String>, private val 
    ticketsOnGoing: List<TicketModel>, private val ticketUpcoming: List<TicketModel>,
                           private val user: UserModel, private val bearerToken: String) : FragmentStateAdapter(fa) {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return tabs.size
    }
    
    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        when(position){
            0 -> return BookingsTabFragment(ticketsOnGoing, position, user, bearerToken)
            1 -> return BookingsTabFragment(ticketUpcoming, position, user, bearerToken)
        }
        return BookingsTabFragment(ticketsOnGoing,0, user, bearerToken)
    }
    }
```

The tab fragment:

```kotlin
        class BookingsTabFragment(private val bookingsList: List<TicketModel>, val position: Int, val user: UserModel, private val bearerToken: String) : BaseFragment() {
    
    lateinit var buttonTest : Button
    
    
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val v: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_bookings, container, false)
    
   if (bookingList.isEmpty()) {
       llMessageBookingsFragment.visibility = View.GONE
       rv_bookings_list.visibility = View.VISIBLE
       buttonTest = v.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_test)
    
            buttonTest.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Prueba", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                //IT NEVER ENTER HERE!!
            })
   } else {
      llMessageBookingsFragment.visibility = View.VISIBLE
      rv_bookings_list.visibility = View.GONE
       ...
```

The XML of tab fragment:

```xml
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_message_bookings_fragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:visibility="gone"
        android:clickable="true">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Prueba"/>
        ...
   </LinearLayout>
   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_bookings_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        tools:listitem="@layout/row_bookings"
        tools:visibility="visible"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In the tab fragment, I use RelativeLayout. The order of the components is very important for this issue, so I put the recycler view before the layout with the button.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_bookings_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools:listitem="@layout/row_bookings"
    tools:visibility="visible"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_message_bookings_fragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:visibility="gone"
    android:clickable="true">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Prueba"/>
    ...
```